# How to refresh custom user control in WPF from code behind or by binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

I have a TabControl and users controls are in TabItem content like that:

```
\\...
<TabItem.Content>
<vm:myUserControl />
</TabItem.Content>
\\...
<TabItem.Content>
<vm:otherUserControl/>
</TabItem.Content>
```

How can I update `myUserControl` when I change data in `otherUserControl` (example add element in list who must be showed in  `myUserControl`)  . This controls have different datacontext (from different viem model class, who inherits `BaseViewModel`. who impelments `INotifyPropertyChanged`). Data is provided by WCF client service. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a Mediator/Messenger or EventAggregator. so your otherUsercontrol raise the message/event and your myUserControl subscribe and react to this message/event.

or if you dont want loose coupling you could of course couple your two viewmodels direct and use some event.

Comment: I used Mediator. Works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve this.  One way would be to fire an event in `otherUserControl` and subscribe to that event in your `MainWindow` and allow your `MainWindow` to update `myUserControl`.

**MyUserControl XAML**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextValue">Initial Text</TextBlock>
```

**OtherUserControl XAML**

```
<Button Click="Button_Click">Click Me</Button>
```

**OtherUserControl C#**

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.ButtonClicked != null)
    {
        this.ButtonClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
    <vm:MyUserControl x:Name="MyUserControl"/>
    <vm:OtherUserControl x:Name="OtherUserControl"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**MainWindow C#**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.OtherUserControl.ButtonClicked += OtherUserControl_ButtonClicked;
}

void OtherUserControl_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MyUserControl.TextValue.Text = "Updated Text";
}
```

Another option is to use something like the [Prism Event Aggregator](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Event%20Aggregator) which will allow `MyUserControl` to subscribe to events raised by `OtherUserControl` without requiring that `MainWindow` setup the communication between the two.  This is a much better option on larger projects since it allows your components to truly be loosely coupled.